# Generation of random variables

Tags: r

I have a problem about the generation of random variables with R .

I have to generate random variables

```
$X_{ij}$ (i=1,...,25, j=1,...,5 ) knowing that
```

each X_ij follows a binomial distribution

```
$X_{ij} \sim Bin(n_{ij}, p_{ij})
```

$and I know already

```
$n_{ij}$ and $p_{ij}$
```

for each index. How to generate these random variable?

I don't know if it could be useful, but I have generated `$p_{ij}$` knowing that they are also random variable which follow a beta distribution (hence actually `$X_{ij}$` follow a beta binomial)

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you had the following matrices for n and p:

```
(n <- matrix(4:7, nrow=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    6
# [2,]    5    7
set.seed(144)
(p <- matrix(rbeta(4, 1, 2), nrow=2))
#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.1582904 0.2794913
# [2,] 0.5176909 0.2889718
```

Now you can draw samples X_{ij} with something like:

```
set.seed(144)
matrix(apply(cbind(as.vector(n), as.vector(p)), 1, function(x) rbinom(1, x[1], x[2])), nrow=2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    2
# [2,]    2    2
```

The `cbind` part of this expression builds a 2-column matrix containing each (n, p) pairing and the `apply` part draws a single binomially distributed sample for each (n, p) pair, with the `matrix` part converting the resulting vector to a matrix.